# Text not aligning in center

Tags: html, css

I have created 4 columns. The first 3 columns are supposed to contain text vertically oriented. The problem is I am unable to align it. justify-content and align-items are not positioning the text in the center of the column. If you run the code you'll see it's positioned to the right. I want it to be exactly in center.

```css
body{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}
.forAll{
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justfiy-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;

}
.verticalOption{
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    line-height: 10px;
}
.verticalOption a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<body>
    <div class="no-gutters">
        <div class="fluid-container d-flex flex-row-reverse">
            <div class="container col-xl-9 col-9 col1 forAll bg-primary"></div>

            <div class="container col-xl-1 col-1 col2 forAll bg-warning">
                <h1 class="verticalOption"><a href="#">Sample Text</a></h1>
            </div>

            <div class="container col-xl-1 col-1 col3 forAll bg-danger">
                <h1 class="verticalOption"><a href="#">Sample Text</a></h1>
            </div>

            <div class="container col-xl-1 col-1 col4 forAll bg-success">
                <h1 class="verticalOption"><a href="#">Sample Text</a></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added another flex container to the column, so alignment can be controlled further into the `HTML` nesting. I also justified the content of the column to `center`. I also made the `h1` display `inline-flex` to remove all extra white-space.

Here is where all the classes have been added:

```html
<div class="container col-xl-1 col-1 col2 forAll bg-warning d-flex justify-content-center">
  <h1 class="verticalOption d-inline-flex m-0">
    <a href="#">Sample Text</a>
  </h1>
</div>
```

### Demo

```css
body{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}
.forAll{
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justfiy-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
}
.verticalOption{
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    line-height: 10px;
}
.verticalOption a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<body>
    <div class="no-gutters">
        <div class="fluid-container d-flex flex-row-reverse">
            <div class="container col-xl-9 col-9 col1 forAll bg-primary"></div>

            <div class="container col-xl-1 col-1 col2 forAll bg-warning d-flex justify-content-center">
                <h1 class="verticalOption d-inline-flex m-0"><a href="#">Sample Text</a></h1>
            </div>

            <div class="container col-xl-1 col-1 col3 forAll bg-danger d-flex justify-content-center">
                <h1 class="verticalOption d-inline-flex m-0"><a href="#">Sample Text</a></h1>
            </div>

            <div class="container col-xl-1 col-1 col4 forAll bg-success d-flex justify-content-center">
                <h1 class="verticalOption d-inline-flex m-0"><a href="#">Sample Text</a></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do text-align:center on your h1.

If that doesn't work, its most likely cause you're hardcoding your width to your a tag, and that 200px is probably larger than the container itself.

Comment: not working. and now i've removed the hardcoded width as well. still no luck

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I had a typo in `justify-content: center` which was causing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add two lines in `.verticalOption`:

```
vertical-align:center;
display:table-cell;
```

and delete `justfiy-content: center;`